# What's the best practice for this with Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Let's say you have this simple markup.

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <h1> title </h1> 
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

If I wished to add a `margin-top` to bring the `h1` down towards the center of the container (*it will position it self at the very top by default*), would it be better to apply this onto the `h1`, `.row` or `.col-md-12` ?

For example:

```
.row {
 margin-top: 100px;
}
```

**Update**: This is **NOT** a 'primarily opinion-based' question since depending on where I applied the style, it could break the expected behavior when it comes to the responsive side of things. Dawood Awan's answer is a perfect example of the legitimacy of this question and how it is not about opinion.

Comment: the h1 tag. applying the style to the row or the col-md div might cause a layout issues on a different screen size

Comment: You've closed your h1 with a h2 :)

Comment: Why are people voting to close this? It's a pretty logical question.

Comment: AlexG's answer will prove useful for others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Rules to Bootstrap:

**Use rows and columns alternating** 
Rows have a negative margin to ensure that the columns respect the containers width.

```
container
|   row
|   |   column
|   |   |   row
|   |   |   |   column
|   |   |   |   column
|   |   |   row
|   |   |   |   column
|   |   |   |   column
|   |   column
```

---

**Always include col-xs-* on columns** 
This is to prevent floating issues. If your column is supposed to be 12 wide anyways dont just ignore the col-xs-12

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
      Some stuff
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Mobile first** 
Start with the smallest screen size. Go from xs < sm < md < lg and you should be all good!

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      Some stuff
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Small columns serve as larger columns** 
A sm column does serve as a md column as well, if not specified otherwise.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
      This is the same
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      as this one
  </div>
</div>
```

---

And at last:
**Do not style rows and columns!** 
Feel free to add classes to modify them, but do not override them in any way!

**Bad example:**

```
.row {
  border: 5px solid pink;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    This is a no-go!
  </div>
</div>
```

**Good example**

```
.pink-bordered {
  border: 5px solid pink;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

<div class="row pink-bordered">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    Totally fine
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your particular case you want a new class for your `h1`. Unless it is global default, then you should style the h1 directly.

Comment: Excellent explanation

Comment: If I were to offset a column using `.col-xs-4 .col-sm-4`, would I use the offset  class with `xs` or `sm`? e.g. `col-*-offset-4`

Comment: xs and sm determine on which breakpoint your column applies. xs~mobile sm~tablet. If you want a offset in xs but not in sm you'll have to reset it. Imagine it like another column in front of it.