# One div won't align with the rest xs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

This is what I'm talking about. https://skullscream.github.io/tributepage/

When it's `col-lg` it gets aligned nicely but when you scale it down completely to `col-xs` and `col-sm` the "biography" paragraph isn't aligned with the rest. Can someone explain it to me why this is happening? I'd rather to get an explanation than the solution :)

HTML

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Arial;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
}

/* Section 1 */

.heading-pictures {
    margin-top: 2%;
}

#top-picture {
    margin-bottom: -4%;
}


.paragraph {
    background-color: #95a5a6;
    padding: 2%;
    color: white;
    text-align: justify;
}

.title {
    position: absolute;
    color: #6c7878;
}

.hd1 {
    font-size: 5.25em;
}

.hd1,
.hd2 {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 15%;
    line-height: 1;
}

.hd2 {
    padding-top: 5%;
    border-top: 1px solid #6c7878;
}

.section1 {
    position: relative;
}

div.paragraph-quote {
    margin-bottom: 4%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
}
  
hr.style-one {
    border: 0; 
  height: 1px; 
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #f0f0f0, #8c8b8b, #f0f0f0);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #f0f0f0, #8c8b8b, #f0f0f0);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #f0f0f0, #8c8b8b, #f0f0f0);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #f0f0f0, #8c8b8b, #f0f0f0);
}

/* Section 2 */

.inventions {
    width: 100%;
}

.images {
    margin-top: 2%;
}

.section2 p {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    color: #6c7878;
    padding-top: 2%;
}

.section2 div {
    padding-bottom: 2%;
}

.tesla-patents p {
    text-align: justify;
    color: white;
    background-color: #95a5a6;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 1.5%;
    margin-top: 1%;
}

.tesla-patents p span a {
    color: white;
    background-color: #95a5a6;
    font-style: italic;
    float: right;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.tesla-patents p span a:hover, 
.tesla-patents p span a:visited {
    color: white;
    background-color: #95a5a6;
    font-style: italic;
    float: right;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/* Section 3 */

.bio-heading {
    font-size: 2.5em;
    color: #6c7878;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
}

#detailed-bio p {
    text-align: justify;
    color: white;
    background-color: #95a5a6;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 1.5%;
    margin-top: 1%;
}

#detailed-bio p a {
    color: white;
    background-color: #95a5a6;
    font-style: italic;
    float: right;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#detailed-bio p a:hover, 
#detailed-bio p a:visited {
    color: white;
    background-color: #95a5a6;
    font-style: italic;
    float: right;
    text-decoration: underline;
}


footer {
    font-size: .7em;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
    text-align: center;
}

#detailed-bio {
    margin: 0 1% 0 1%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Nikola Tesla, Engineer and Inventor</title>
    <link href="tribute.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  
<head>
  <title>Nikola Tesla, Engineer and Inventor</title>
</head>


<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
      
      <!-- Section 1 -->
      <div class="row">
          <div class="section1 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
           <div class="title col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-3 col-md-offset-1 col-md-3 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"><p class="hd1">Nikola Tesla</p><p class="hd2">Inventor and Engineer</p></div>
            <div class="heading-pictures col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-6 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-12">

              <img class="img-responsive" id="top-picture" src="http://www.anonews.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/kak_360001.jpg" alt="Image of Nikola Tesla">
            </div>

            <div class="paragraph-quote col-lg-7 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-7 col-lg-offset-1 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
              <p class="paragraph">"The day science begins to study non-physical phenomena, it will make more progress in one decade than in all the previous centuries of its existence." &nbsp;&nbsp;- Nikola Tesla</p>  
            </div>
          </div> 
      </div>
      
      <hr class="style-one">
      
      <!-- Section 2 -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="section2 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <p>What is Nikola Tesla known for?</p>
        <div class="images col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <img class="img-responsive inventions" src="images/hose-coupling-power-cable-strange-black-64025.jpeg">
        </div>
        <div class="images col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <img class="img-responsive inventions" src="images/pexels-photo-109998.jpeg">
        </div>
        <div class="images col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <img class="img-responsive inventions" src="images/sound-speaker-radio-microphone.jpg">
        </div>
      
          <div class="tesla-patents col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-11 col-xs-12">
            <p>Nikola Tesla was an inventor who obtained around 300 patents worldwide for his inventions. Some of Tesla's patents are not accounted for, and various sources have discovered some that have lain hidden in patent archives. There are a minimum of 278 patents issued to Tesla in 26 countries that have been accounted for. Many of Tesla's patents were in the United States, Britain, and Canada, but many other patents were approved in countries around the globe. Many inventions developed by Tesla were not put into patent protection. <span><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Nikola_Tesla_patents" target="_blank">Source</a></span></p>
          </div>
            </div>
    </div>
      
      <hr class="style-one">
      
      <!-- Section 3 -->
      
    <div class="row">
        <div class="bio-section col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <p class="bio-heading">Biography</p>
         <div id="detailed-bio">   
            <p>Nikola Tesla was born on July 10, 1856 in Smiljan, Lika, which was then part of  the Austo-Hungarian Empire, region of Croatia. His father, Milutin Tesla was a Serbian Orthodox Priest and his mother Djuka Mandic was an inventor in her own right of household appliances. Tesla studied at the Realschule, Karlstadt in 1873, the Polytechnic Institute in Graz, Austria and the University of Prague. At first, he intended to specialize in physics and mathematics, but soon he became fascinated with electricity. He began his career as an electrical engineer with a telephone company in Budapest in 1881. It was there, as Tesla was walking with a friend through the city park that the elusive solution to the rotating magnetic field flashed through his mind. With a stick, he drew a diagram in the sand explaining to his friend the principle of the induction motor. Before going to America, Tesla joined Continental Edison Company in Paris where he designed dynamos. While in Strassbourg in 1883, he privately built a prototype of the induction motor and ran it successfully. Unable to interest anyone in Europe in promoting this radical device, Tesla accepted an offer to work for Thomas Edison in New York. His childhood dream was to come to America to harness the power of Niagara Falls....<span id="read-more-link"><a href="http://www.teslasociety.com/biography.htm" target="_blank">Read more</a></span></p> 
        </div>
      </div>
        
  </div>
      <hr class="style-one">
        <footer>Website created by Milan for FreeCodeCamp. 25.8.2016.</footer>
   
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `If you need the code, you can download the zip file here https://github.com/skullscream/tributepage` , no, if you need help, put the code here

Comment: add some code, the question is not clearly

Comment: @MihaiT I though because it's a long code it would be unclean to do but I will add it.

Comment: the biography seems to be aligned, the one not aligned is `.tesla-patents` because it has these classes : `col-md-11 col-sm-11` change them to `12` instead of `11`

Comment: Yes I changed those now that I realized it. But biography isn't aligned in any other but `col-lg`. Well at least when I resize it. You can see in xs on the screenshot that the paragraph goes over. [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/xlrgSFM.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because you're using the bootstrap syntax incorrectly (partly).

When using columns alternate columns and rows. You're currently nesting columns in columns.

```
container
|   row
|   |   column
|   |   |   row
|   |   |   |   column
|   |   |   |   column
|   |   |   row
|   |   |   |   column
|   |   |   |   column
|   |   column
```

This might help you as well: **[Bootstrap Guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38375257/whats-the-best-practise-for-this-with-bootstrap#answer-38375322)**

---

### Adjusted code:

Remove the margin on `#detailed-bio` and adjust the code like so:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Section 1 -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="section1 col-xs-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="title col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-3 col-md-offset-1 col-md-3 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                    <p class="hd1">Nikola Tesla</p>
                    <p class="hd2">Inventor and Engineer</p>
                </div>

                <div class="heading-pictures col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-6 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-12">
                    <img class="img-responsive" id="top-picture" src="http://www.anonews.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/kak_360001.jpg" alt="Image of Nikola Tesla">
                </div>

                <div class="paragraph-quote col-lg-7 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-7 col-lg-offset-1 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                    <p class="paragraph">"The day science begins to study non-physical phenomena, it will make more progress in one decade than in all the previous centuries of its existence." &nbsp;&nbsp;- Nikola Tesla</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <hr class="style-one">

    <!-- Section 2 -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="section2 col-xs-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <p>What is Nikola Tesla known for?</p>
                </div>
                <div class="images col-lg-4 col-xs-12">
                    <img class="img-responsive inventions" src="images/hose-coupling-power-cable-strange-black-64025.jpeg">
                </div>
                <div class="images col-lg-4 col-xs-12">
                    <img class="img-responsive inventions" src="images/pexels-photo-109998.jpeg">
                </div>
                <div class="images col-lg-4 col-xs-12">
                    <img class="img-responsive inventions" src="images/sound-speaker-radio-microphone.jpg">
                </div>

                <div class="tesla-patents col-xs-12">
                    <p>Nikola Tesla was an inventor who obtained around 300 patents worldwide for his inventions. Some of Tesla's patents are not accounted for, and various sources have discovered some that have lain hidden in patent archives. There are a minimum of 278 patents issued to Tesla in 26 countries that have been accounted for. Many of Tesla's patents were in the United States, Britain, and Canada, but many other patents were approved in countries around the globe. Many inventions developed by Tesla were not put into patent protection. <span><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Nikola_Tesla_patents" target="_blank">Source</a></span></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <hr class="style-one">

    <!-- Section 3 -->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="bio-section col-xs-12">
            <p class="bio-heading">Biography</p>
            <div id="detailed-bio">
                <p>Nikola Tesla was born on July 10, 1856 in Smiljan, Lika, which was then part of  the Austo-Hungarian Empire, region of Croatia. His father, Milutin Tesla was a Serbian Orthodox Priest and his mother Djuka Mandic was an inventor in her own right of household appliances. Tesla studied at the Realschule, Karlstadt in 1873, the Polytechnic Institute in Graz, Austria and the University of Prague. At first, he intended to specialize in physics and mathematics, but soon he became fascinated with electricity. He began his career as an electrical engineer with a telephone company in Budapest in 1881. It was there, as Tesla was walking with a friend through the city park that the elusive solution to the rotating magnetic field flashed through his mind. With a stick, he drew a diagram in the sand explaining to his friend the principle of the induction motor. Before going to America, Tesla joined Continental Edison Company in Paris where he designed dynamos. While in Strassbourg in 1883, he privately built a prototype of the induction motor and ran it successfully. Unable to interest anyone in Europe in promoting this radical device, Tesla accepted an offer to work for Thomas Edison in New York. His childhood dream was to come to America to harness the power of Niagara Falls....<span id="read-more-link"><a href="http://www.teslasociety.com/biography.htm" target="_blank">Read more</a></span></p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <hr class="style-one">
    <footer>Website created by Milan for FreeCodeCamp. 25.8.2016.</footer>
</div>
```

(removed unnecessary bootstrap classes)

Comment: So you are saying I should add another row and another col after the `.bio-section`? Tried it, still the same somehow.

Comment: Fixed. Now it's working awesomely. THANKS!!! Did only removing the unnecessary classes and margin on `#detailed-bio` make it work or there was something else to it? (BTW now I learned that I don't always need all col classes I though I had to have them all)

Comment: The problem was the inconsistency between rows and columns :) And some col classes weren't necessary because the smallest column works on larger columns as well, if not specified otherwise. e.g. `col-xs-4` will always be 4 columns - `col-xs-4 col-md-8` will be 4 columns in xs,sm and 8 columns in md,lg. Of course you can keep the classes, it's just my preference. Keeps the code cleaner

Comment: Mindblown :P yes it looks neater if there's no unnecessary code.

Answer (score 1):

Edit this div

```
<div id="detailed-bio">
  <p></p>
</div>
```

To

```
<div id="detailed-bio" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: This does worsen the problem in xs.

Answer (score 0):

increase the margin-left and margin-right of detailed-bio div into 2%. Like below

`#detailed-bio {
    margin: 0 2% 0 2%;
}`

Comment: That makes `col-lg` scale differently.

Comment: add this style to particular  col-xs media query only.
for example see below:
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px){
 
 }