# Bootstrap Grid sometimes started from right side in new row

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Sometimes if the last grid height is different from others then in the next row new grid starts from right side. It will clearly shown in the below image.

[image: Grid Height problem]

I have used `<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">` for that division. Is there any problem with this.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yes this happens because of diff height of `div`, this happens when you use `float`, if your code is static, batter to use `row` for each `grid-set` or set any min-height which suits all div's height

Comment: Is all images in same fixed size ?

Comment: This happens because your col-xx-3 have different heignt. To solve in simple way force the height or use .row every 4 elements.

Answer (score 1):

This happened because Bootstrap's columns are styled with CSS `float`.

```
.col-xs-1, .col-xs-10, .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12,
.col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5,
.col-xs-6, .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9 {
    float: left;
}
```

As you have multiple `col-xs-*` elements in a single `.row`, you can replace this `float` with `inline-block` to fix this problem.

```
.aligned-items > .row {
  letter-spacing: -4px;
  font-size: 0;
}
.aligned-items > .row [class^="col-"] {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  float: none;
}
```

```css
.aligned-items > .row {
  letter-spacing: -4px;
  font-size: 0;
}
.aligned-items > .row [class^="col-"] {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  float: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container aligned-items">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="..." alt="...">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="..." alt="...">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="..." alt="...">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="..." alt="...">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. ultricies vehicula ut id elit. ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="..." alt="...">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="..." alt="...">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 4th element is smaller than the rest, the browser tries to fill the remaining space since there is no more space on the right.

Try rows of 4 columns or nest columns.

> **Use rows and columns alternating**
>  Rows have a negative margin to ensure that the columns respect the containers width.
>
> ```
> container
> |   row
> |   |   column
> |   |   |   row
> |   |   |   |   column
> |   |   |   |   column
> |   |   |   row
> |   |   |   |   column
> |   |   |   |   column
> |   |   column
> ```

**[Click for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38375257/whats-the-best-practice-for-this-with-bootstrap#answer-38375322)**